# r Group by and count

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, plyr, reshape2

I am dealing with a dataset which is as follows

```
      Id     Date           Color
      10     2008-11-17     Red
      10     2008-11-17     Red
      10     2008-11-17     Blue
      10     2010-01-26     Red
      10     2010-01-26     Green
      10     2010-01-26     Green
      10     2010-01-26     Red
      29     2007-07-31     Red
      29     2007-07-31     Red
      29     2007-07-31     Blue
      29     2007-07-31     Green
      29     2007-07-31     Red
```

My goal is to create a dataset like this

```
     Color      Representation      Count            Min   Max
     Red        1 + 1 + 1  = 3      2 + 2 + 3 = 7    2     3
     Blue       1 + 1      = 2      1 + 1            1     1
     Green      1 +  1     = 2      2 + 1            1     2
```

**Representation**

The value in 1<sup>st</sup> Row , 2<sup>nd</sup> column (Representation), is 3 because Red is represented three times based on the unique combination of ID and Date. For example, 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> rows are the same, Id(10) and Date(2008-11-17) so this combination is represented once (1<sub>(10, 2008-11-17)</sub>). The 4<sup>th</sup> and 7<sup>th</sup> rows are the same  Id(10) and Date(2010-01-26)combination, so this unique combination, is represented once (1<sub>(10, 2010-01-26)</sub>) . The 8<sup>th</sup>, 9<sup>th</sup>, 12<sup>th</sup> are the same combinations of Id(29) and Date(2007-07-31) and similarly this is represented once (1<sub>(29, 2007-07-31)</sub>). Thus the value is 3 in row 1, column 2.

1<sub>(10, 2008-11-17)</sub> + 1<sub>(10, 2010-10-26)</sub> + 1<sub>(29, 2007-07-31)</sub> =3

**Count**

The value in 1<sup>st</sup> Row , 3<sup>rd</sup> column (Count), is 7 because Red is mentioned twice by ID `10` on `2008-11-17` (2 <sub>10, 2008-11-17</sub>), again Red is mentioned twice by ID `10` on `2010-01-26`  (2 <sub>10, 2010-01-26</sub>) and three times by ID `29` on `2007-07-31` 2 <sub>29,2007-07-31</sub>

2<sub>(10, 2008-11-17)</sub> + 2<sub>(10, 2010-10-26)</sub> + 3<sub>(29, 2007-07-31)</sub>

Any help on accomplishing this unique frequency/count table is much appreciated.

**Dataset**

```
Id   = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,29,29,29,29,29) 
Date = c("2008-11-17", "2008-11-17", "2008-11-17","2010-01-26","2010-01-26","2010-01-26","2010-01-26",
         "2007-07-31","2007-07-31","2007-07-31","2007-07-31","2007-07-31") 
Color = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red") 
df = data.frame(Id, Date, Color)
```

Comment: two tables? `cbind(data.frame(table(df$Color)), Rep = colSums(!!table(interaction(df$Id, df$Date), df$Color)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Representation = uniqueN(paste(Id, Date)), Count = .N) , by = Color]
#     Color Representation Count
#1:   Red              3     7
#2:  Blue              2     2
#3: Green              2     3
```

#### Update

For the second question, we can try

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- sapply(split(df[["Color"]], list(df$Id, df$Date), drop = TRUE),  function(x) table(x))
v1 <- (NA^!m1) * m1
df1 <- data.frame(Color = row.names(m1), Representation = rowSums(m1!=0), 
   Count = rowSums(m1), Min = rowMins(v1, na.rm=TRUE),
    Max = rowMaxs(v1, na.rm=TRUE))
row.names(df1) <- NULL
df1
#   Color Representation Count Min Max
#1  Blue              2     2   1   1
#2 Green              2     3   1   2
#3   Red              3     7   2   3
```

Comment: this is perfect, but another question i have is, how do i include a column for range(Max-min), IQR (Interquartile Range) for values in Count column ? sorry I should have included in my question earlier.

Comment: @HeatherKeturah  Did you meant `setDT(df)[, .(Representation = uniqueN(paste(Id, Date)), Count = .N) , by = Color][, c("Min", "Max", "Iqr") := .(min(Count), max(Count), IQR(Count))][]`

Comment: @HeatherKeturah  Or if you want to use the `range` function, then `setDT(df)[, .(Representation = uniqueN(paste(Id, Date)), Count = .N) , by = Color][, c("Min", "Max", "Iqr") := c(as.list(range(Count)), IQR(Count))][]`

Comment: something is not right with the output from the min and max function. I am  seeing all 2s in the Min column and all 7s in the Max column for all the three colors (Red, Blue, Green), it should be Min = 2 and Max = 7 for row Red, Min =1, Max = 1 for row Blow, Min =1 and Max =2 for Row Green..??

Comment: @HeatherKeturah I am not sure how you got that values.  Baseed on the output showed here, there is not that infor about 1, 1, or 1, 2 for Red and Green

Comment: i just updated the expected output table in my question with this Min and Max column, please let me know if this is still confusing :)

Comment: @HeatherKeturah  If you need the IQRs, then `rowIQRs(m1)` would be the other column

Comment: that was perfect. I never new about the matrixStats package i am looking at the documentation for this package and I am finding lot of interesting stuff. Thanks much I wish i could give 100 points :)

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Color) %>%
    summarize(Representation = n_distinct(Id, Date), Count = n())
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#    Color Representation Count
#   <fctr>          <int> <int>
# 1   Blue              2     2
# 2  Green              2     3
# 3    Red              3     7
```

Comment: that was perfect, how do i capture the range (max-min) for the values in column Count  and also IQR (Interquartile Range) ?

Comment: With the `range()` and `IQR()` functions, respectively.

Comment: :) those two didnt work, so I tried this , `min(n())`, and `max(n())`, i am not getting the right values,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `aggregate()` function:

```
# Make a new column for the Date-Id joined (what you want to base the counts on
df$DateId <- paste(df$Date, df$Id)

# Get the representation values
Representation <- aggregate(DateId ~ Color, data=df,FUN=function(x){length(unique(x))})
Representation
#>   Color DateId
#> 1  Blue      2
#> 2 Green      2
#> 3   Red      3

# Get the Count values
Count <- aggregate(DateId ~ Color, data=df,FUN=length)
Count
#>   Color DateId
#> 1  Blue      2
#> 2 Green      3
#> 3   Red      7
```